# Thymeleaf and th:if not skipping text when null

Tags: spring-boot, if-statement, thymeleaf

I understand that you should be able to "skip" text printing if Object is null, in thymeleaf, using th:if.

However my page throws Null error at line 23. (second div)

```
        <div th:if="${Brackets}">
            <th:block th:each="brackets : ${Brackets}">
                <div th:if="${brackets.brackets}">
                    <tr th:each="bracket : ${brackets.brackets}">
                        <td th:text="${bracket.lower}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${bracket.higher}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${bracket.prc}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </th:block>
        </div>
```

What am i missing here?

Solved with "?"
Many thanks to Patrick!

```
<div th:if="${Brackets} != null">
            <th:block th:each="brackets : ${Brackets}">
                <div th:if="${brackets?.brackets} != null">
                    <tr th:each="bracket : ${brackets?.brackets}">
                        <td th:text="${bracket.lower}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${bracket.higher}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${bracket.prc}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </th:block>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation that `th:if` checks null values. Anyway this should work `th:if="${Brackets} != null`

Comment: I dont have any Doc link right now, but when i google this people seem to give it as a solution. Either way with th:if="${Brackets} != null i still get error about object being null... I dont understand..

Comment: thats strange. Maybe there is a naming issue because of using brackets twice. Can you try to use save navigation? Means `brackets?.brackets`.

Comment: Whelp, atleast the "?" works. I would love to know whats wrong tho.. But thank you so much! Cant paste new code here but i put it in question. if you post that as answer i can accept it.

Comment: Note that `Brackets` and `brackets` differ only in case; this is at the least confusing, and may be the source of some of your problems.

Comment: well, im not saying it's good practice, it's propably not. But thats how i've done this for long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its strange that the null check does not work. It could be that the naming has some issues. Anyway, a short way to use null objects savely is to use `save navigation`. You use it with the `?` operator:

```
<div th:if="${brackets?.brackets} != null">
```